# Out of scope in KVC generated array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, key-value-coding

I'm trying to create an array of objects from a hierarchy of other objects like this:

code 1:

```
childController.names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Person *p in list.persons) {
    [childController.names addObject:p.name];
}
```

code 2:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [list.persons valueForKey:@"name"];
```

The first code snippet works perfectly, returning an array of persons' names. In contrast, the second returns an array with the correct number of persons' names,  but they are shown as  "Out of scope" when I debug the code in XCode. When I'm trying to access one of them, the app terminates with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x72e0620'

The list, persons are Core Data managed objects if it matters.. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Also, if your `names` property is a `retain` property, you're leaking when you set it with `[[NSMuatableArray alloc] init]` (well, you'll have +2 retain count after you've set your property).

Comment: Hmm, can you explain this a bit more? What would be the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the type of `persons`. It seems like it is a `NSSet`, and `valueForKey:` on `NSSet` will return a `NSSet`. This code snippet should work as expected:

```
NSSet* testSet = [list.persons valueForKey:@"name"];
```